# How do I activate a Unity license for the 2021 version of the editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Basically, I have 2 editors installed, 2020 and 2021. When I try to activate a license in Unity Hub 2.x.x it works smoothly with the 2020 editor but when I switch to 2021 it says "No valid license...".
Before you ask, Unity Hub 3.x.x doesn't work at all; can't save the manual activation file, can't activate normally... basically nothing license-related works.

I tried (on 2.x.x) to manually activate it, normally activate it, return the license and nothing works. I even tried changing the unity version in the Unity_lic file to 2021.3.15 (target version) but that didn't work either.
Also, when I return the license and activate a new one, it still gives me the old 2018 date which is when I originally activated it.
What I think the problem might be:

- the fact that I took all the files from my old machine and just moved them to my new machine which may have messed up the license
- the fact that I have two unity versions installed and linked in the hub
  All in all, I've been working on this lowkey for 3 weeks now (although I first encountered the problem months ago) and it's really bugging me.
  Thank you in advance!

EDIT: After checking the logs I discovered that it's a Machine Binding issue (it's not matching). I then tried completely uninstalling Unity and deleting everything related to it and even making a new Unity ID. Still, when I install Hub 3.5.0 on this machine it simply doesn't work, however, it works flawlessly on my laptop (previous machine). And I still get the same Machine Binding error despite having re-installed everything and activated a fresh new license.

Comment: I have ~6 different Unity versions installed through hub and activation works for me on all of them. It seems unlikely that is the issue.

Comment: nope, ive moved machines a few times. still got my old license

Comment: Is the license other than Unity Free, like Pro. etc?

Comment: @Obscure021 It's a free license, btw if you know more about it please check the edit/update

Comment: Have you deleted files from Appdata?

Comment: @Obscure021 Yep, I even tried freshly reinstalling Unity which means deleting everything Unity related